# get all the process in my computer in uwp

Tags: uwp, windows-10

I have a problem when I having my UWP development.In my application, I need to get all the apps details(including its displayname or the ExecutableFileName), which is running in the computer.

My first solution is to to use the `System.Process` class, and I do it like

```
    private void Mybutton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var apps = Process.GetProcesses();
        ...
    }
```

But it is not availbale in the UWP and throws a exception when I try to do it.

Secondly,I have tried the `System.AppDiagnostics` class, but the class only show the UWP applications details.

And, what have disappointed me a lot is that, when I try to find solution in website. Nearly all the advice does not work, and I have found that UWP apps are sandboxed, that means, there is limited ways to do it.

This part will be the most important part in my application.So I have a question, how can I know all the process details in my computer. And I will appreciate a lot if you can provide me with helpful solutions, thanks.

Comment: Your question touches some aspects of WinXX process details as found in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer  There are refs in the link for how all this hangs together.

Comment: It seems like a win32 process… do you mean what I need is to add a dll build with c++ to finish it?@jdv

Comment: What I mean is that this subject is huge, and sysinternals approaches magic for what it does. But you might be able to steal ideas from there.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a try by myself.@jdv

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Currently, You could use [**UWP App Diagnostics**](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/06/28/uwp-app-diagnostics/) to get info of the running uwp app that contain Win32 process.

The final versions for the upcoming release are available in the Insider builds from Build 16226, along with the corresponding SDK.

At a high level, these APIs allow an app to:

> Enumerate a list of running apps, including **UWP** apps, **Win32** apps, system services and so on.

[image]

And this UWP Task Monitor [code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/AppModelSamples/tree/master/Samples/UWPTaskMonitor) that you could refer.

Comment: I find this Very Useful. My mind was in a sandbox and I always sought for a FullTrustProcessLauncher + App Service solution for this kind of requirement.

Comment: Oops, it is so helpful. Thank you so much for your kindness :)

Comment: Well, I have just noticed the checkItem under the vote, I am new to the community. Your answer have been accepted, hope it helps more people worry about the same problem :)