# UWP How to get PID for app triggred using Launcher?

Tags: c#, uwp, diagnostics

In my UWP app I use Launcher to open a file(for instance txt) by default app.

```
bool isFileOpen = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(storageFile);
```

Above method uses default app (for instance notepad.exe) to open a file (for instance txt). Once app gets launched, the new process is created. I would like to know PID and Status of that Process. Why? I want to monitor it's Status to determine if the app (like notepad.exe which opened the file) gets closed.

Is any solution to get those infos like showed in Task Manager?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get all the process in my computer in uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51386038/get-all-the-process-in-my-computer-in-uwp)

Comment: @Access Denied Your example just show how to get all running process. In my case want to know PID and Status for process which has been created as a result of launching default app (for instance notepad.exe to open given file). Thanks for it I could check that Process's Status (Running/Suspended).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LaunchFileAsync` method just tells the operating system (OS) to start the default app associated with the specified file. It doesn't know about nor return any PID or other information about the process that eventually gets started by the OS.

So I am afraid you can't get this information without looking at all processes and somehow trying to figure out which ones that were started as a result of your app calling the `LaunchFileAsync` method. You might for example get all running processes just before you call the method, and then again immediately afterwards. But the API itself doesn't return anything useful in regards to this.

Comment: I have already AppService which uses appDiagnostics restricted capability for gathering info about all processes done. Therefore, I thought it must be some API which might cover mine problem. I'm don't want to try sth which might categorize my app as a side-loaded. If solution doesn't exist, how then manage scenario for monitoring specific process by UWP app ?

Comment: I listened your advice. Get processes before and after Launcher. I get always 1 result which must be a process I am looking for.